# Run setup code exactly once for different test statements using timeit

Tags: python, profiling, timeit

Using `timeit`, I have a `setup` code block which sets up a data structure filled with dummy data, and I have two statements (say, `test1` and `test2`) which retrieve data from this data structure in different ways.

When I do

```
t = timeit.Timer(test1, setup)
print t.timeit(3000)
t = timeit.Timer(test2, setup)
print t.timeit(3000)
```

I notice that the setup is run twice, once for each test. Is it possible to make the two tests share the same setup, i.e. run `setup` code block exactly once and use the exactly the same data structure created for both tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to put the setup code into a module `setup.py`, and then use

```
"from setup import name_1, name_2, name_3"
```

as `setup` parameter to `timeit.timeit()`.  (Note that wildcard imports won't work correctly in that situation.)

If you don't want to use a separate module, put the code in the main module and use

```
"from __main__ import name_1, name_2, name_3"
```

Comment: Doesn't this run `setup` twice, too? I thought each `timeit` call gets its own new and clean namespace.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, thanks for the suggestion, but how is this different from the approach in my example?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: A clean namespace of course, but it still shares the interpreter (and hence `sys.modules`) with the calling code, so modules still get imported only once.

Comment: @skyork: The difference is that modules are imported only once, so the code in the setup module is executed only once.